# Create string value for post request using quotations ES6

Tags: javascript, string, reactjs

So i'm trying to create a json string that looks like this:

```
{
    "username": "John",
    "email": "johndoe@gmail.com",
    "address": "123 Fake St",
    ...
}
```

This is what I have:

```
stringPost += fieldName + ": " + fieldValue +", ";
```

And then I'm JSON.stringifying it. But it needs those necessary quotes. What I have returns like this:

```
"username: John, email: johndoe@gmail.com, address: 123 Fake St, " 
// all in one wrapping quote: not what we need
```

I need it like this:

```
{"username": "john", "email": "johndoe@gmail.com"... // quotes with each value
```

I've tried adding the proper ' vs " quotes, but it just renders with \username... Help!

Comment: `JSON.stringify` takes an object as its parameter, not a string... Why not just create an object `var jsonObj = {}` and then do `jsonObj[fieldName] = fieldValue` for your fields, then `JSON.stringify(jsonObj);`?

Comment: But, to do things your way, you just want `stringPost += '"' + fieldName + '": "' + fieldValue + '"';`

Comment: @TAGraves i'd like to use your first suggestion. but I'm looping through each field and appending it to this string. So for each field return `stringPost += '"' + fieldName + '": "' + fieldValue + '"';` Adding it to one variable stringPost which I will later append to an ajax call

Comment: @TAGraves any suggestions on how to remove that last comma if its the last in the loop? Or should I just create a new question for that?

Comment: There's no reason why you can't do what I suggested in your loop. Just declare `jsonObj` before the loop and use the code I suggested in the loop. That's definitely the right way to go about this, rather than string concatenation.

Comment: If you know the comma is going to be the last character in the string, you can just do `stringPost = stringPost.slice(0, -1);` to remove the comma.

Comment: @TAGraves post your first suggestion as an answer (creating an object) its definitely the right way to go about this

Comment: if you use JSON.stringify on your object it will be the exact representation you are looking for? am I missing something? did you do any research on this? `var a = {b: 'some val', c: 'other val'};`..... `JSON.stringify(a)`.... outputs `'{"b":"some val","c":"other val"}'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON.stringify takes an object as its parameter, not a string. Rather than using string concatenation, just create an object and set its keys to the fieldnames and values to the fieldvalues:

```js
var jsonObj = {};
// now within some loop:
jsonObj[fieldName] = fieldValue;
// after the loop:
var ajaxString = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);
```